# Does a 16"W x 13" deep counter space need an electrical outlet?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, receptacle

I have a 15"W x 24" Deep base cabinet. The counter top overhang is 1" on the front and right side. There is no overhang on the left side as there is a gas range there. There is a 15" W x 12" deep cabinet that sits on top of the base cabinet and goes up to the ceiling.

This leaves a counter space that is 16" W x 13" Deep, and no wall space (due to the tall cabinet) to put an electrical outlet.

Would this be considered a peninsula and not require an outlet because the long side is under 24" or would it be considered a regular counter space (over 12" W)and require an outlet within 24" of any spot along the wall?

Answer (score 1):

> 210.52(C)(3) Peninsular Counter Spaces. At least one receptacle outlet shall be
>   installed at each peninsular counter space with a long dimension of 600 mm (24 in.) or greater and a short dimension of 300 mm (12in.) or greater.

So yes according to the NEC you do need an outlet.  But it is really really close to not meeting the specifications, meaning it might be easier calling your inspector than it is debating with us.

Comment: I think the question is "Does this counter count as a peninsula?", not "What are the spacing requirements for a peninsula?". I would say it sounds like a wall counter. But I agree, asking the inspector is really the best way to determine.

Answer (score 0):

Since the counter & cabinets are along a wall, I don't see how this would count as a peninsula. As you probably know, a wall counter requires an outlet if the width is at least 12". But as @DMoore says, the best way to figure this out is to ask an inspector.

If it turns out you need/want an outlet, maybe you could put one on the wall next to the cabinet (that would still let you be within 24"), or install one in the side of the lower cabinet. Personally I would want an outlet there.

Comment: "...or install one in the side of the lower cabinet"; except that would be against code. The only provisions which allow a receptacle to be installed below a counter top is: (1) for the physically impaired and (2) on an island/peninsula. I think you hit the nail on the head about it not being that so...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: that's a good point, although the NEC does seem to leave a little wiggle room for the inspector to approve a recepticle below a counter if there are space constraints. I think we can all agree that the easiest way forward is just to ask the inspector.